# Zend php code completion netbeans 7.2

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, code-completion

I would very much like to use code completion for php Zend framework in Netbeans 7.2. I am running the Windows Zend CE server.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get code completion for variables into zend_view using netbeans 6.9.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120571/how-to-get-code-completion-for-variables-into-zend-view-using-netbeans-6-9-1) or [How to setup zend auto complete in NetBeans on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487737/how-to-setup-zend-auto-complete-in-netbeans-on-ubuntu)

Comment: See this answer for a quick guide on how to set it up. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9309393/212940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have Netbeans for PHP installed. ( http://netbeans.org/features/php/ )

When you create a new project (or in project properties), you can select Zend library (and others (Doctrine, etc..) for code completion and other tasks.

Hope this helps.